# Pass multiple variable with POST method in React app

Tags: reactjs, postgresql

I'm trying to post multiple variables to my Postgres database using a form with React.

This is my current script:

```js
const InputAddress = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [problem, setProblem] = useState("");
  const [date, setDate] = useState("");

  const onSubmitForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const body = {
        name,
        problem,
        date,
      };

      console.log(params);
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/logements", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });
      console.log(response);
      window.location = "/";
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="text-center mt-5">Add your address</h1>
      <form className="d-flex mt-5" onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label>Comment</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          value={problem}
          onChange={(e) => setProblem(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label>Date</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          value={date}
          onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

My problem seems to be with the fetch method.

When I submit the form, I get this error message in the console :

```
bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 3
```

Is there a simple fix to this problem?

Comment: I don't think you should ```JSON.stringify``` your body, try without

Comment: Almost but got this error message : SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: remove also the ```headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },``` maybe